# Can't load component though URL changed

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I have this route which loads a component and makes some validations

```
{
path: "/sso/:id/:atex/:entityId/:ip",
name: "SSO",
component: () => import("./views/account/sso"),
meta: {
  beforeResolve(to, routeFrom, next) {
    if (localStorage.getItem('userDetails') || localStorage.getItem('user')) {
      next({ path: "/" + to.params.entityId })
    }
    next();
  }
},
```

}

In the component and if user is valid

```
this.$router.replace("/" + this.$route.params.entityId);
```

And here's the route of `/`

```
{
path: "/:entityId?",
name: "Companies",
meta: {
  authRequired: true,
  beforeResolve(routeTo, routeFrom, next) {
  next();
  },
},
component: () => import("./views/dashboards/CompaniesGrid"),
```

},

And in the component I search for a table cell that contains the entityId value and click it to naرigate to `/dashboard`

```
var len = document.querySelectorAll('td').length;
  for (var i=0; i < len; i++){
    if ( document.querySelectorAll('td')[i].innerText == (this.$route.params.entityId).toUpperCase()){
      document.querySelectorAll('td')[i].setAttribute('id', this.$route.params.entityId);
      document.getElementById(this.$route.params.entityId).click();
    }
  }
```

The URL changes successfully but it doesn't really navigate. The component of dashboard isn't loaded and when I click it manually I get

```
Uncaught (in promise) NavigationDuplicated: Avoided redundant navigation to current location: "/dashboard".
```

How to solve this issue and why did it happen?

Comment: You either never resolve the navigation Promise - or your component has an error in the middle of rendering.

Comment: No errors at all in the console

Comment: Is the navigation shown in Vue DevTools?